# Output variable value with gin framework

Tags: go, logging

I want to see the value of a variable in the interface function, I tried fmt, logging, but I can't see the output of this variable when I run the service

```
// @Router /job/batchadd [post]
func HandleBatchAdd(c *gin.Context) {
    var req reqBatchCreate
    var resp respBatchCreate
    err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&req)
    if err != nil {
        helper.ReplyErr(c, errcode.ErrInvalidParam, err)
        return
    }
    ...


    resp.JobIDs = ids
    logging.Default().Info(" HandleBatchAdd api ids= ", ids)
    helper.Ok(c, resp)
    return
}
```

For example, In this code , I don't know where I can see the output information , logging Default().Info and helperReplyErr

Comment: I think I'm not able to understand what you are asking. You will see the logging output in your terminal error stream and response in your server's response payload. 
If you don not see logging info then perhaps your log level is too high, but not sure what logging library you are using and we don't know what your helper.* methods are doing. 
Perhaps you should reformat your code with vanilla GIN and try again.

Comment: have you tried, logging error, when binding `c.ShouldBindJSON(&req)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have solved the problem, although I did not use the output log to determine the error. I will analyze it again later when I have time based on your suggestion.